# CSS navbar with form and few buttons causing the form to make a newline

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see, the form seems to create new lines before and after itself. I am using Twitter Bootstrap, so I tried `.form-inline` but it didn't work either. Is there a way to keep the form inline with other elements?

Below is JSFiddle to the source code written below it. It doesn't show much, but the behavior of the form is shown.

http://jsfiddle.net/UHNtA/

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
  <div class="container">


      <div class="login-widget pull-right">

        <button id="login-toggle" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-white icon-chevron-left"></i>Log in</button>
        <form id="login" class="navbar-form form-inline" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
          <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Username" name="username">
          <input type="password" class="span2" placeholder="Password" name="password">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Log in</button>
        </form>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'/register.php'?>'">Register</button>

      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your login form to display: inline:

```
#login {
  display: inline;
}
```

See updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UHNtA/1/

Comment: does work but I'm using twitter bootstrap to assign form as .navbar-form which aligns things properly within navbar. i'm looking for a way to use this option as well as to put the form inline

Answer (score 0):

the reason why its been creating lines before and after your from, you've put them outside your form, you need to include your `login` and `register` inside your `<form>` tag

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nY89/54/